# Visual Studio 11 - Design view is unavailable for x64 and ARM target platforms because the document contains custom elements

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm test-driving Visual Studio 11 beta and it appears I've hit a major snag.

Has anyone tried opening an actual production WPF project that contains WPF windows with User Controls? When I try to open a WPF Window or control that contains user controls, the design view displays a nice error message:

> "Design view is unavailable for x64 and ARM target platforms because the document contains custom elements."

It appears to be a major wtf... since most developer machines these days are x64.

*** UPDATE: ***

Reproduced this in a new VS 2011 WPF project:

1. Add a xaml resourec file with styles (in the same project as the user control)
2. Reference this file in a user control using the  tag

Immediately, the "Design view is unavailable for x64 and ARM target platforms..." pops up.

As soon as I remove the resource reference, the designer starts working again.

Comment: I am also having the same issue (Test driving VS11 + Win8 64bits)

Answer (score 4):

The "x64 or ARM" in the message refers to the current target configuration of the project, not to the machine on which Visual Studio is running.  That is, if you change the target platform configuration of the project to x86 or Any CPU, you should not get this message.

You can change the target platform from the Standard Toolbar (select the "Add or Remove Buttons" item at the end of the toolbar, and select "Solution Platforms").

If your solution platform is x86 or Any CPU, please add a comment to this post and let me know.  I'd be interested in investigating.

Comment: The target platform is AnyCPU. 
Even if it is connected to the solution platform - why should it matter?
Do I have to set my project to "x86" to design, then to "Any CPU" or "x64" to build, if it requires e.g. x64 components?!?

Comment: ok... tried shifting to x86, now it dies on styles referenced from a binary.
In any case - it should not happen. Seems like the Blend Designer addition totally put developer functionality & productivity on the sidelines.

Comment: The XAML designer is an x86 process and can only load x86 (or AnyCPU) binaries.  If support for loading x64 (or other) binaries is important to you, please consider opening a bug on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) or on the [Visual Studio UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com) site.

Comment: I see the repro steps that you've added to the question; I'll look into it and get back to you.

Comment: Hi, James! Please wait with your effor for a day or so... I'm trying this from several angles and it appears not to work only from a specific existing project of mine (that I presently use to hold all the styles for a specific solutaion), while it works from the same style xaml that I copy into a new project. I'll investigate this further, and then post again.

Comment: I managed to repro this in a fresh solution, however only once - after a VS restart, the styles persist to work, even if the referenced assemblies holding the styles do not compile (?). We still have issues with production projects, where we get either the Designer unavailable error, or the "Cannot find resource" error on a resource that clearly exists. All builds & runs fine, it's just the designer that's creating difficulties.
I have put together a solution I used for repro, and a word document with screenshot & more detailed description... if you have time & interest to take a look.

Comment: If you would file a bug at [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) with your repro, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Already done. Hope something good comes of it. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727684/vs-11-wpf-designer-doesnt-work-with-user-controls-on-a-x64-machine#tabs

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this by doing the following in Visual Studio:

1. Select the solution node within Solution Explorer.
2. Within the Properties pane, set "Active config" to an x86 processor type.
3. Display Properties for application project.
4. Select the Build tab on the navigation pane.
5. Ensure "Platform target" is set to x86.

After completing these steps:

1. Restart Expression Blend.
2. Observe the designer is now loaded with UI