# Design view can't show xaml design if i use a ResourceDictionary

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

In my phone application I've made a user control. Everything works, until I add a ResourceDictionary:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../AppStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

When I add the above xaml I'm still able to build and run the application, and it works as it should with the defined styles, but in Visual Studio the Design view now states:

```
Design view is unavailable for x64 and ARM target platforms.
```

Removing the above xaml resolves the problem, but then I cant style the buttons by using a resource dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the **ResourceDictionary** to the **Application.Resources** in **App.xaml**, it will solve the problem.

```
<Application.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../AppStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

OR you can switch the project **platform** to **x86**.

> Configuration manager => Platform => x86

Extra info about the problem: [Design view is unavailable for x64 and ARM target platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523319/visual-studio-11-design-view-is-unavailable-for-x64-and-arm-target-platforms-b)

Comment: Added it to App.xaml! Awesome :D