# What processor architecture should I choose for an app destined to run on Windows? x64, or ARM?

Tags: wpf, arm, 64-bit, bing-maps, cpu-architecture

I am creating a WPF / XAML app. When I try to drag a Bing Map control onto my WPF form, I get:

[image]

I then tried to build the project, and got these two msgs:

```
Warning 1   Project "Platypus" depends upon SDK "Bing Maps for C#, C++, or Visual Basic v1.0" 
which supports apps targeting "Windows 8.0". To verify whether "Bing Maps for C#, C++, or Visual Basic v1.0" is compatible with "Windows 8.1", contact the SDK author or see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309181.

Error   2   The processor architecture of the project being built "Any CPU" is not supported by the 
referenced SDK "Bing.Maps.Xaml, Version=1.0". Please consider changing the targeted processor 
architecture of your project (in Visual Studio this can be done through the Configuration Manager) to one of the architectures supported by the SDK: "x86, x64, ARM".
```

What processor architecture should I choose for an app destined to run on Windows? x64, or ARM?

### UPDATE

So I changed the project to x86, and now when I go to the Designer, it tells me, "Design view is unavailable for x64 and ARM target platforms."

### UPDATE 2

So I tried the "fix" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523319/visual-studio-11-design-view-is-unavailable-for-x64-and-arm-target-platforms-b), but it didn't help - I still see that same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess using the x64 is good since you are trying to build a desktop application. ARM is actually an architecture for embedded systems. Desktop computers have two architecture x86 which is know as 32bit and x64. x64 architecture can support more RAM and x86 only supports 3GB of RAM so you can get more power. But if you built it on x64 Architecture, x86 can't use it.. and if you built it on x86, x64 can use it. You make the choice.

Comment: I reckon "nobody" still uses x86 - those are years old, right?

Comment: yes.. x64 is way more better but I disagree that no one uses x86, There are still people who uses it, because x64 requires 2gb of ram or more.

Comment: Okay, "nobody" who would spend money on a Windows Store app.